# How to mount a LUKS encrypted device with password prompt NOT at bootime?

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption, luks

I would like to automate the process of doing

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc sdc_crypt
sudo mount /dev/mapper/sdc_crypt /mnt/data
```

in one line with

```
mount /mnt/data
```

and only be prompted for the device's LUKS password.

I thought this configuration should be enough, but it's not, how should I do ?

/etc/crypttab

```
sdc_crypt   /dev/sdc    none    luks,noauto
```

/etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/sdc_crypt   /mnt/data   ext4   defaults,user,noauto 0 2
```

Comment: I wonder if this is something systemd's mount and automount units were supposed to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting with password prompt:

```
systemctl start mnt-data.mount
```

umounting with luksClose

```
systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@sdc_crypt.service
```